# How to negate a case pattern

Tags: shell, case

How add I add the condition in case whereby if it does not detect the required conditions, it will execute the command.

My code:

```
case $price in
[0-9] | "." | "$") echo "Numbers, . , $ Only"
            ;;
esac
```

This command will execute if it detects numbers, "." and "$". How do change it in a sense if it does not detect those, the command will execute. Or are there other better commands to use to do this function.

Comment: If I recall, there is a way to use ANDs ORs and NOTs to create an XOR situation.

Comment: Is it even possible to do the function I need ? @mdpc

Comment: Are you sure `[0-9] | "." | "$"` matches what you want? I would rather expect something like (in bash with `extglob` enabled): `?($)+([0-9])?(.+([0-9]))` (matching `$123.45`

Comment: Sorry, i just started shell about 2 weeks ago, do you mind explaining what your code does ? @HaukeLaging

Comment: That's the shell version of a regular expression. You should provide some example input for what and what shall not match.

Comment: the examples are as of above, it's a function to add price, so in price terms, there should only be numbers, "." and "$", how do i do it in a way, if it detects either of the 3 above, it will continue the function as per normal @HaukeLaging

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a default case:

```
case $price in
[0-9] | "." | "$") true
            ;;
*) 
   do-something
   ;;
esac
```

Comment: can't get it to work, the true, is it a string ? Or it's a function

Comment: @Zac it's a command that does nothing and has exit status zero. Run `/bin/true` to check, if you wish. What's your error, exactly?

Comment: still figuring out, it's a syntax error, but i tried your codes on a test script and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 2):

This answer does not refer to the already explained `case` problem but to the matching problem.

First we need a definition what the valid strings may look like. The easiest definition would, of course, allow only one structure like

1. start with one or more digits (leading zeroes allowed)
2. decimal dot
3. two trailing digits (if necessary `00`)
4. Dollar sign (no leading space)

As a regular expression (for e.g. `grep`, see `man 7 regex`) this would be written as:

```
^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]\$$
```

- `^` marks the beginning of the string i.e. there can be nothing before the `[0-9]+`
- The dot is escaped `\.` in order to be treated as literal dot
- The Dollar sign is escaped `\$` in order to be treated as literal
- the trailing `$` marks the end of the string i.e. there can be nothing after the literal `$`

Testing:

```
> echo '0123.45$' | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]\$$'
0123.45$
```

If the definition is changed so that both the dot with the trailing digits and the Dollar sign are optional then the regex would change to

```
^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\$?$
```

Testing:

```
> echo '0123$' | grep -E '^[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]\$$'

# no match
> echo '0123$' | grep -E '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\$?$'
0123$
> echo '0123.45$' | grep -E '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\$?$'
0123.45$
```

The shell can work with regular expressions directly but not within `case` patterns. You need the `[[  ]]` structure. But as you want to know only whether a string matches or not anyway there is no reason to use `case`:

```
if [[ "$price" =~ ^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\$?$ ]]; then
  :
else
  :
fi
```

If you really need `case` then you can set the option `extglob` with the shell bulitin `shopt` and rewrite the regex to a "shell regex":

```
shopt -s extglob
```

`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?\$?$` becomes then

```
+([0-9])?(.[0-9][0-9])?($)
```

**leading $**

If you want `$0123.45` instead of `0123.45$` then you obviusly have to put the check for `$` at the start:

- `grep` / `[[ ]]`: `^\$?[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9])?$`
- shell pattern matching: `?($)+([0-9])?(.[0-9][0-9])`

**easier check**

If you don't care about the order but just about the right chars then you can use much easier expressions:

- `grep` / `[[ ]]`: `^[0-9.$]+$`
- shell pattern matching: `+([0-9.$])`

**example**

```
#! /bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

for value in 1234 1234EUR; do
    case "$value" in
            +([0-9]))
                    echo "value OK: '${value}'"
            ;;
            *)
                    echo "value not OK: '${value}'"
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: sorry for the dup, after many tries, i still can't get it to work, what do i have to put into the case condition without adding other stuff.

    "$" | [0-9]* | "."

currently using this to catch for un-required characters

Comment: guess i'm gonna use if, tried your code, if i key in $10.00, it failed, any help on this ?

Comment: @Zac I have extended the answer by a trivial change. If an answer doesn't work for you then write a comment to that answer. Do not ask a new question about that; it would get closed.

Comment: thanks, works perfect, learn something new as well, sorry, i'm still new to this.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, i have another function with requires a simple check, and i was hoping not to use if, just by using case, the condition is simple, just to check if the number is a positive whole number, i know [0-9]* checks for positive number, but it doesn't check for whole number, what should i do ?

Comment: @Zac `[0-9]*` matches the empty string, too. You probably want `[0-9]+` (i.e. at least one char). I don't understand "whole number". What is that supposed to mean? That there is no dot? As in my examples you have to define start and end of the string: `^[0-9]+$`

Comment: your examples are for -if- uses, which works perfectly for input values that requires to meet very specific conditions. As of now, i'm using case to do the matching, and yes, my meaning for whole number is number without dot. In -case- usage, [0-9]* catches positive whole number (including those with dot). I want it to catch positive whole number, but not those with dots.

Comment: @Zac The problem is that you mix up regular expressions with shell pattern matching. With `case` you need pattern matching but `[0-9]*` is a regex. So you have to enable `extglob` with `shopt -s extglob`. After that you can use this expression for `case`: `+([0-9])` For the usage with `case` you need an additional closing bracket: `+([0-9]))`

Comment: Sorry, is it possible for you to create a simple script example, it would be easier for me to understand

Comment: @Zac I had added an example.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - `[0-9]*` is a shell pattern as well - it will match any string beginning with a digit. I wholeheartedly disagree with your recommending `[[ ... =~ pat ]]` over `case` - the latter is both portable and easier to read. If a regex is needed `grep` is always available - it is very capable and often does a quicker job than a shell will so long as the shell script is ordered responsibly.

Comment: @mikeserv That was bad wording by me, syntactically you are right: `[0-9]*` is a shell pattern. But there is the context of what is needed and this expression (nearly) does the right check (`^$` missing) if used as a regex. It does not the right check if used as a shell pattern. What is considered easier to read is a personal decision thus I am perfectly OK with you feeling (and recommending) differently.

Comment: @HaukeLaging - good point about personal preference - sorry to foist that on you. The disagreement stands - but amicably.

Comment: Hauke - by the way, if you did `[[ ${string:--} =~ [0-9]* ]]` it would always *only* match a positive integer - even in a null/unset `$string` case.

Comment: @mikeserv But I never recommended that, did I? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/178832/how-to-negate-a-case-pattern/178971?noredirect=1#comment298978_178971 Apart from that: Why would one want to match a null string in this context?

Comment: What I meant was - if you get a null valued `$string` to expand to a not-null string that *won't* match `[0-9]*` like `[[ ${string:--} =~ [0-9]* ]]` then the fact that the pattern `[0-9]*` can match a null string becomes irrelevant because it still won't match `-`. Although - it could match the null string before or after the `-` - does that happen in `[[ ... ]]`? If so then `^[0-9]*$` would still handle all cases.

Answer (score 1):

To match a string containing only a single, positive integer with a shell `case` statement you can do:

```
case "${string:--}" in
(*[!0-9]*)  
! echo 'Invalid value for $string!';;
(*[!0]*) 
echo "$string is a positive integer greater than 0.";;
(*)
echo "$string is 0.";;
esac
```

In the first `case` match I screen for any value of the `${string:--}` expansion that contains even a single character which is not among `0123456789`. In the event `$string` is either unset or null it will expand to `-` and so still match this pattern. The leading `!` inverts `echo`'s return *(which is always 0)* to a 1 - and so the `case` construct returns 1 if `$string` contains an invalid value.

In the next I match any value for `$string` containing a single digit which is not 0 - and so any number of leading 0s on any valid value for `$string` will match as a positive number.

The last matches any which did not match the previous two - which is to say it matches only one or more 0s.